# How to Display a div on mouse-over using jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover

I have [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/K2RAt/).

I want to show specific div hover of specific  hover.
I have made function also in that will show div on hover but it's not working.

and I am confused that how to make one function for each  tag.
right now I have made only one function for that.

Code :

```
<a class="cart" href="#"> show </a><br>
<a class="cart1" href="#"> show1 </a><br>
<a class="cart2" href="#"> show2 </a><br>

<div class="laptop" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;">
    laptop
</div>
<div class="mobile" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;">
    mobile
</div>
<div class="shoes" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;">
    shoes
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.laptop{
    display: none;              
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 400px:
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;               
}
.mobile{
    display: none;                  
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 200px:
    position:absolute;
    background-color: blue;            
}
.shoes{
    display: none;                  
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 200px:
    position:absolute;
    background-color: red;             
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.cart', function () {                       
        $(this).next(".laptop").show();

    }).on('mouseleave', '.cart', function () {
        $(this).next(".laptop").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/K2RAt/1/

changed

```
$(this).next(".laptop").hide();
```

to

```
$(".laptop").hide();
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Sir will you help me to do same for all div ? actually i want to do that on drop down list but right now I am just doing test on it.

Comment: Sir suppose I want to do this using drop down list then I have to add function onChange() of that ?  and I have to pass value of it to function ? am I right sir ?

Comment: yap. Correct. Try to code it if you face issue then we are here :)

Comment: If this helped you please dont forget to select it as answer :)

Comment: Yes I ll do that, don't worry.

Answer (score 4):

Add a common class to all the anchor elements like `cart` then add another additional `data-*` to specify the selector of the element to be displayed

Try

```
<a class="cart" data-target=".laptop" href="#"> show </a>
<br>
<a class="cart" data-target=".mobile" href="#"> show1 </a>
<br>
<a class="cart" data-target=".shoes" href="#"> show2 </a>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.cart', function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.cart', function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H2Jpd/)

Comment: Sir suppose I want to do this using drop down list then I have to add function onChange() of that ? and I have to pass value of it to function ? am I right sir ?

Comment: @Arun P Johny -- will $(this).data('target') work like $(this).find('.laptop')?

Comment: @C-link becase `this` is the anchor element and `.laptop` is not a descendenant of the anchor element

Comment: @C-link `$(this).data('target')` returns the value of `data-target` which can be `.laptop` or `.mobile` this is passed to another jQuery call like `$('.laptop')` which will return the target element. It is same as writing `var selector = $(this).data('target');
        $(selector).show();` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H2Jpd/2/

Comment: It means this or any selector would be ignored and just works as $(selector). thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
<a>Hover</a>
<div>To be shown</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
 $( ".cart1" ).mouseover(function(){
       $('.laptop').show();
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitlamba009/K2RAt/7/)

Answer (score 2):

I have just updated your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/K2RAt/4/

Only need `$(".laptop").show();`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer CSS only...

Assuming HTML4, with this markup:

```
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

You can do something like this:

```
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/z6tL9

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BF7F/5/)
:

```
[HTML:

<ul id="menu" class="menu">
  <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu1" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK1</a>
      <div id="menu1content" class="menuDescription">
        Description for "menu1"
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu2" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK2</a>
      <div id="menu2content" class="menuDescription">
         Description for "menu2"
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu3" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK3</a>
      <div id="menu3content" class="menuDescription">
         Description for "menu3"
      </div>
    </li>
  <li id="menu4" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK4</a>
      <div id="menu4content" class="menuDescription">
         Description for "menu4"
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
CSS:

.menu{
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    position: absolute;
    top:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    right:100px;
    float:right;

}
.menu ul{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.menu li{
    float:left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
}
.menu li a{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.menu li .menuDescription {
    display: none;
}

.menu li:hover .menuDescription {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 120px;
}

.menuDescription  {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a custom attribute in anchor tag with target Div Id like :

```
<a class="cart" href="#" target_id='laptop'> show </a><br>
```

And then use following script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('mouseenter', '.cart', function () {                       
              var cl  = $(this).attr('target_id');
                jQuery('div.'+cl).show()
              }).on('mouseleave', '.cart', function () {
                 var cl  = $(this).attr('target_id');
                   jQuery('div.'+cl).hide();
              });
});
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jn9eT/1/

Hope, it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class to all the anchor elements like cart then add another additional data-* to specify the selector of the element to be displayed

Try this : -

```
<a class="cart" data-target=".laptop" href="#"> show </a>
<br>
<a class="cart" data-target=".mobile" href="#"> show1 </a>
<br>
<a class="cart" data-target=".shoes" href="#"> show2 </a>
```

then after : -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.cart', function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.cart', function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).hide();
    });
});
```

[Show this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Jpd/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use: -

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
     $('.cart').hover(function(){
           $(".laptop").show();
     })
 });
```